# Get sum and order by the last date added

Tags: mysql, sql

Using the below query to calculate the total balance:

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(credit_in)-SUM(credit_out), 2) as balance,
cw.date_added as last_updated_date
FROM customer_wallet cw
LEFT JOIN customers c ON c.id = cw.cus_id
GROUP BY cw.cus_id
ORDER BY cw.date_added DESC
```

Also, using order by date_added to get the last added date. But, getting the first date record for each customer. How can I get the last date?

This is SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/585fd2/1

From SQLFiddle, if you will run the query, you will get `2022-12-01T00:00:00Z` as last updated date. But, I want, `2022-12-04T00:00:00Z`

Please let me know if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `max` function

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(credit_in)-SUM(credit_out), 2) as balance, max(cw.date_added) as last_updated_date
FROM customer_wallet cw
LEFT JOIN customers c ON c.id = cw.cus_id
GROUP BY cw.cus_id
ORDER BY cw.date_added DESC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/585fd2/2